# Вывод комментариев из базы данных WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

У меня есть сайт на WP, на нем есть нужная страница на которой нужно сделать вывод всех комментариев с базы данных WP,решил делать вывод из бд на php (редактор Gutenberg), я скачал плагин EzPHP на WP, сделал проверку, написав в редакторе [php] echo "тест"; [/php], все работает. Но только я начал делать больше строк в коде

```html
[php]
$i = 1;
if ($i == $i) {
echo "Тест";
}
[/php]
```

код прератился в это в редакторе:

```html
<p>[php]</p>
<p>$i = 1;</p>
<p>if ($i == $i) {</p>
<p>echo "Тест";</p>
<p>}</p>
<p>[/php]</p>
```

Все строки превратились в абзацы, поэтому код не работает. Как быть? С WP знаком очень мало. Буду благодарен если поможете.

Comment: Почитайте создание шорткодов

Comment: Хорошо, попробую сделать через создание шорткодов)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для вывода комментариев для страниц и записей уже давно есть стандартная функция [wp_list_comments](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_comments). Используйте её.